# The get_key() function of Python "inputs" library never returns

Tags: python, input, keyboard

I am trying to get the keystrokes from my keyboard using the Python "inputs" library. I am running the following code:

```
from inputs import get_key 
events = get_key()
```

This code causes the python to enter some sort of loop. However, the code never leaves this loop no matter what key I press. When I press ctrl-c to exit I get the message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> NameError: name 'asdw' is not defined

"asdw" is the keys I pressed while the code was running. Why does my code never exit or record my keystrokes?

Comment: What you are describing is the correct behavior of ```get_key()```. What you probably want is keyboard input from python's built-in ```input()```.

Comment: I don't want to press enter like I would have to do with input(). I want my program to constantly monitor what I am typing. I also need my program to monitor controller button presses, so I plan to use the get_gamepad() method of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this I believe:

```
from inputs import get_key
while 1:
    events = get_key()
    for event in events:
        print(event.ev_type, event.code, event.state)
```

referring to: https://pypi.org/project/inputs/0.1/